# How to sync different social networks in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, twitter, google-plus

I am developing an iOS app that has a number of Social Networks to be integrated such as Facbook,Twitter,Google+,LinkedIn,Tumblr,Wordpress,FourSquare.What my client needed is , a member should authenticate to all social network at the time of creating his account.And once he has completed the registration process along with the above steps he will get an account to which he can get signed in.
Once he get signed in to the app with his username & password,he can write something in his app and it should be shared to all network without having any other authentication dialogue boxes of corresponding  social network.

For Example,if user A has logged in to the app,his post must be shared to all his social network accounts(For ex: A@facebook.com,A@Twitter.com,A@google.com etc.) without any SN  dialogue boxes at that time and if user B has logged in to the app,his post must be shared to all his social network accounts(For ex: B@facebook.com,B@Twitter.com,B@google.com etc.) without any SN  dialogue boxes in the similar manner.

Is there any way to do that? Thanks in advance.

-----------------------------------------------------------Update-------------------------------------------------------------
 The Scenario is in a same device:

Step 1:A user(say A) starts creating an account > Authenticates each SDKs > Signs out

Step 2:Another user(Say B) starts creating an account > Authenticates each SDKs  > Signs out

Step 3: User A > Logs in the app > Posts some thing > It posts to all SDKs with his accounts

Step 4: User B > Logs in the app > Posts some thing > It posts to all SDKs with his accounts

So my question is in the case of step 3,How do the SDKs knows the post should be sent to A's authenticated Social Network accounts?

Similar to the step 4 in the case of B.

The user should not have authentication box at the time of Step 3 & 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are building something like a broadcasting app. What you want is possible.

When you are telling your user to authenticate in different social networks using oAuth make sure to get permissions to post on his/her behalf. That way when the user posts something on your app you will have the permissions to post on his behalf to various networks.

I cant help you with the specifics as one needs to look into the API implementation of oAuth for each networks but i think you got the idea. its fairly easy to do.

**UPDATE:** To answer your question. in your backend servers, you maintain a one-to-many mapping between the user and all his social accounts, which will essentially be his userID->(different oAuth tokens). Now when the user A posts something since you know in backend his userID you can easily get his oAuth tokens for different networks. Isn't that what you want? Hope that solves it.

Comment: Thank you for you comment.But actually my doubt is,in the app there my be N number of users using the same device.So if a user(say A) logs in the app and posts something how do the app or SDK understands whether it is A or B is accessing the SDK for posting in the behalf of a user?

Comment: Thank your Srikar for your valid comment.2 more doubts.Is the oAuth token cannot be expired?I have integrated Facebook & Twitter not using oAuth.It has been developed using Social.Framework & the recent Facebook SDK of iOS.So what can I do in their case of Twitter & Facebook?Are they also providing oAuth tokens?

Comment: yes oAuth tokens can expire. This depends on that particular social network. Different networks have different policies regarding this. coming to your second question, yes they provide oAuth tokens. Please upvote and/or mark the answer as ACCEPTED if my answer has helped you. Thanks...